# Get screenshot as Byte array on windows, wrong bmp header data

Tags: c++, image, winapi, io

I'm trying to get a screenshot data using c++ and windows api to byte array of data representing a bitmap image, and then save it to the disk. My code is based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59776238/how-do-i-get-the-byte-representation-of-a-bitmapfileheader-and-bitmapinfoheader)

The saved image cannot be opened in windows photo viewer, however i can open it in gimp and the image is visible but gimp give me a warning: that gimp-image-set-resolution failed, resolution was out of range, so default resolution is used. so i guess something is not correctly copied in the header data of the bitmap.

here is the full code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <fstream>



void WINAPI CaptureScreenIntoByteArray(BYTE*& screen_bytes, DWORD& screen_bytes_size)
{
    BITMAPFILEHEADER bfHeader;
    BITMAPINFOHEADER biHeader;
    BITMAPINFO bInfo;
    HGDIOBJ hTempBitmap;
    HBITMAP hBitmap;
    BITMAP bAllDesktops;
    HDC hDC, hMemDC;
    LONG lWidth, lHeight;
    BYTE* sb = NULL;

    ZeroMemory(&bfHeader, sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER));
    ZeroMemory(&biHeader, sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER));
    ZeroMemory(&bInfo, sizeof(BITMAPINFO));
    ZeroMemory(&bAllDesktops, sizeof(BITMAP));

    hDC = GetDC(NULL);
    hTempBitmap = GetCurrentObject(hDC, OBJ_BITMAP);
    GetObjectW(hTempBitmap, sizeof(BITMAP), &bAllDesktops);

    lWidth = bAllDesktops.bmWidth;
    lHeight = bAllDesktops.bmHeight;

    DeleteObject(hTempBitmap);

    bfHeader.bfType = (WORD)('B' | ('M' << 8));
    bfHeader.bfOffBits = sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER) + sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);

    biHeader.biSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
    biHeader.biBitCount = 24;
    biHeader.biCompression = BI_RGB;
    biHeader.biPlanes = 1;
    biHeader.biWidth = lWidth;
    biHeader.biHeight = lHeight;

    bInfo.bmiHeader = biHeader;

    screen_bytes_size = (((24 * lWidth + 31) & ~31) / 8) * lHeight;

    hMemDC = CreateCompatibleDC(hDC);
    hBitmap = CreateDIBSection(hDC, &bInfo, DIB_RGB_COLORS, (VOID**)&sb, NULL, 0);
    SelectObject(hMemDC, hBitmap);

    int x = GetSystemMetrics(SM_XVIRTUALSCREEN);
    int y = GetSystemMetrics(SM_YVIRTUALSCREEN);
    BitBlt(hMemDC, 0, 0, lWidth, lHeight, hDC, x, y, SRCCOPY);

    // copy image data, i guess something is not correctly copied
    screen_bytes = new BYTE[sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER) + sizeof (BITMAPINFOHEADER) + screen_bytes_size];
    std::copy(&bfHeader, &bfHeader + 1, (BITMAPFILEHEADER*)screen_bytes);
    std::copy(&biHeader, &biHeader + 1, (BITMAPINFOHEADER*)(screen_bytes + sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER)));
    std::copy(sb, sb + screen_bytes_size, screen_bytes + sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER) + sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER));



    DeleteDC(hMemDC);
    ReleaseDC(NULL, hDC);
    DeleteObject(hBitmap);
}
int main() {

    //get image data array
    BYTE* screen_bytes = NULL;
    DWORD screen_bytes_size = 0;
    CaptureScreenIntoByteArray(screen_bytes,screen_bytes_size);

    //save image data array as bmp file
    FILE* file = fopen( "output.bmp", "wb" );
    fwrite( screen_bytes, screen_bytes_size, 1, file );
    fclose(file);

   //do further work with image data array
    return 0;
}
```

Image is cannot be read on windows photo viewer, image header may not be written correctly.

**How to properly write a bmp file from the byte data ?**

Comment: The proper way is to let the [Windows Imaging Component (WIC)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wic/-wic-lh) handle the file format encoding. I explained how to do this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48708505/1889329).

Comment: You haven't set the biXPelsPerMeter or biYPelsPerMeter. For 120 DPI, you want e.g. 4724. For 96 DPI, 3780, for 72 DPI,  2834.   This might fix Gimp, but maybe the image is just too big for photo viewer

Comment: The specific bug, I believe, is here: `ZeroMemory(&biHeader, sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER));`. It attempts to zero-initialize the `biHeader` structure but supplies a size that's too small (should be `sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER)`). Bytes beyond the provided size remain uninitialized. An easy way to prevent that from happening is to use C++' aggregate initialization, e.g., `BITMAPINFOHEADER biHeader = {};`.

Comment: You're leaking `screen_bytes` BTW.

Comment: @IInspectable: The common Windows pattern is `BITMAPINFOHEADER biHeader = { sizeof (biHeader) } ;` -- many Windows structures have their size as the first member, this one included. This will still zero all the other fields.

Comment: @MSalters Oh, I didn't even notice *that* bug. With C++20, I'd hope the common pattern would be more like `auto const biHeader = BITMAPINFOHEADER { .biSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER) };`.

Comment: @IInspectable: The problem with that style is that you need the _name_ of the first member. That's usually called `cbSomething` (Count,Bytes) but as this structure shows, not always.  But it's always the first, because the ABI requires it (it's an implicit structure version, new API version => new fields added => larger structure)

Comment: @MSalters The ABI doesn't require any field in a structure to carry any sort of semantic information. The "problem" with the suggestion above is that it fails to compile if assumptions do not hold. I don't know why anyone would call that a "problem."

Comment: Did you see the document [Capturing an Image](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdi/capturing-an-image)?

Answer (score 1):

The code [you've found](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59776238) sets a poor example: It attempts to implement what you should not<sup>1</sup> be implementing and gets it wrong, too. There are *many* issues with the code, and instead of addressing them one by one, let's solve the problem instead.

There are two parts to the problem:

1. Capturing the screen contents.
2. Encoding the screen capture into an image format.

The first part is outlined in [Capture an Image](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdi/capturing-an-image)<sup>2</sup>. The sample implements an entire application that does two things: It scales the screen capture for immediate display and saves it to a file. That's nice, but it also distracts from the core principles. Let's keep things simple<sup>3</sup> and do the bare minimum only:

```cpp
#include <Windows.h>

#include <wil/resource.h>
#include <wil/result.h>

/// @brief Captures the entire desktop into a bitmap resource.
///
/// @param use_alpha Controls whether the returned bitmap contains an alpha
///                  channel.
///
/// @return Returns a `unique_hbitmap` holding the screen contents on success.
///         Errors are reported via C++ exceptions.
///
[[nodiscard]] ::wil::unique_hbitmap capture_desktop(bool use_alpha = false)
{
    // Get DC for the desktop
    auto const desktop_dc = ::wil::GetDC(nullptr);
    THROW_HR_IF_NULL(E_FAIL, desktop_dc);

    // "Borrow" the DC's current bitmap (doesn't need to be cleaned up)
    auto const desktop_bmp = ::GetCurrentObject(desktop_dc.get(), OBJ_BITMAP);
    THROW_HR_IF_NULL(E_FAIL, desktop_bmp);

    // Gather bitmap dimensions
    BITMAP bmp = {};
    THROW_HR_IF(E_FAIL, ::GetObjectW(desktop_bmp, sizeof(bmp), &bmp) == 0);
    auto const cx = bmp.bmWidth;
    auto const cy = bmp.bmHeight;

    // Construct memory DC
    auto const mem_dc = ::wil::unique_hdc { ::CreateCompatibleDC(desktop_dc.get()) };
    THROW_HR_IF_NULL(E_FAIL, mem_dc);
    // Construct DIB
    auto const bmi = BITMAPINFO { .bmiHeader = { .biSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER),
                                                 .biWidth = cx,
                                                 .biHeight = cy,
                                                 .biPlanes = 1,
                                                 .biBitCount = static_cast<WORD>(use_alpha ? 32 : 24),
                                                 .biCompression = BI_RGB } };
    void* pbits = nullptr; // memory is owned by the DIB
    auto mem_bmp
        = ::wil::unique_hbitmap { ::CreateDIBSection(desktop_dc.get(), &bmi, DIB_RGB_COLORS, &pbits, nullptr, 0) };
    THROW_LAST_ERROR_IF_NULL(mem_bmp);

    // Perform the `BitBlt`; the extra scope is required to restore `mem_dc`
    {
        auto const restore = ::wil::SelectObject(mem_dc.get(), mem_bmp.get());
        THROW_LAST_ERROR_IF(!::BitBlt(mem_dc.get(), 0, 0, cx, cy, desktop_dc.get(), 0, 0, SRCCOPY));
    }

    // Transfer ownership of `mem_bmp` to caller
    return mem_bmp;
}
```

This implementation captures the desktop into a [DIB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdi/device-independent-bitmaps), optionally including an alpha channel<sup>4</sup>. It has an obvious interface, and that's about the only nice thing about it.

The second part is about image encoding. Windows comes with the [Windows Imaging Component (WIC)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wic/-wic-lh) that provides encoders for many image formats. The following code is a C++ version of the code I published [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48708505/1889329), with these changes:

- It requires a DIB
- It creates and returns an [`IStream`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/objidl/nn-objidl-istream) in memory rather than writing directly into a file
- It implements alpha channel support

```cpp
#include <Shlwapi.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <objidl.h>
#include <ocidl.h>
#include <wincodec.h>

#include <wil/com.h>
#include <wil/result.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "Shlwapi.lib")

/// @brief Encodes a source bitmap `bmp` using the BMP image format.
///
/// @param bmp The image source. This function fails if this isn't a DIB. If
///            `bmp` uses more than 24bpp the encoded BMP contains an alpha
///            channel.
///
/// @return Returns a stream of bytes that represent the encoded image on
///         success. Errors are reported via C++ exceptions.
///
[[nodiscard]] ::wil::com_ptr<IStream> encode_bmp(HBITMAP bmp)
{
    // Validate input (we're expecting a valid DIB)
    THROW_HR_IF_NULL(E_INVALIDARG, bmp);
    auto bmp_info { DIBSECTION {} };
    THROW_HR_IF(E_INVALIDARG, ::GetObject(bmp, sizeof(bmp_info), &bmp_info) != sizeof(bmp_info));
    auto const use_alpha = bmp_info.dsBm.bmBitsPixel > 24;

    // Create a factory that exposes WIC services
    auto const factory = ::wil::CoCreateInstance<IWICImagingFactory>(CLSID_WICImagingFactory);

    // Create a WIC bitmap from the source GDI bitmap
    auto const options = use_alpha ? WICBitmapUsePremultipliedAlpha : WICBitmapIgnoreAlpha;
    ::wil::com_ptr<IWICBitmap> wic_bitmap {};
    THROW_IF_FAILED(factory->CreateBitmapFromHBITMAP(bmp, nullptr, options, wic_bitmap.put()));

    // Create a memory stream the encoder can write into
    auto stream { ::wil::com_ptr { ::SHCreateMemStream(nullptr, 0) } };
    THROW_HR_IF_NULL(E_FAIL, stream);

    // Create a BMP encoder
    ::wil::com_ptr<IWICBitmapEncoder> encoder {};
    THROW_IF_FAILED(factory->CreateEncoder(GUID_ContainerFormatBmp, nullptr, encoder.put()));
    THROW_IF_FAILED(encoder->Initialize(stream.get(), WICBitmapEncoderNoCache));

    // Create and initialize a frame to write into (BMP files only support a
    // single frame)
    ::wil::com_ptr<IWICBitmapFrameEncode> frame {};
    ::wil::com_ptr<IPropertyBag2> enc_options {};
    THROW_IF_FAILED(encoder->CreateNewFrame(frame.put(), enc_options.put()));
    if (use_alpha)
    {
        // Request that WIC writes a `BITMAPV5HEADER`
        // This is required so that image viewers can reliably determine
        // existence of an alpha channel
        OLECHAR name[] = L"EnableV5Header32bppBGRA";
        auto prop { PROPBAG2 { .dwType = PROPBAG2_TYPE_DATA, .vt = VT_BOOL, .pstrName = name } };
        auto val { VARIANT { .vt = VT_BOOL, .boolVal = VARIANT_TRUE } };
        THROW_IF_FAILED(enc_options->Write(1, &prop, &val));
    }
    THROW_IF_FAILED(frame->Initialize(enc_options.get()));
    THROW_IF_FAILED(frame->SetSize(bmp_info.dsBm.bmWidth, bmp_info.dsBm.bmHeight));
    auto pixel_format { use_alpha ? GUID_WICPixelFormat32bppBGRA : GUID_WICPixelFormat24bppBGR };
    THROW_IF_FAILED(frame->SetPixelFormat(&pixel_format));

    // Copy source into frame
    THROW_IF_FAILED(frame->WriteSource(wic_bitmap.get(), nullptr));

    // Commit all writes to the memory stream
    THROW_IF_FAILED(frame->Commit());
    THROW_IF_FAILED(encoder->Commit());

    // Pass ownership of the stream to the caller
    return stream;
}
```

This returns an `IStream` representing the encoded image as a BMP. This isn't an array, but it has similar properties: You can [seek](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/objidl/nf-objidl-istream-seek) to arbitrary positions and [read](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/objidl/nf-objidl-isequentialstream-read) from it just like you would with an array.

Here is an example of a function that copies an `ISream`'s contents into a file:

```cpp
#include <Shlwapi.h>
#include <Windows.h>

#include <wil/com.h>
#include <wil/result.h>

#include <filesystem>
namespace fs = ::std::filesystem;

#pragma comment(lib, "Shlwapi.lib")

/// @brief Creates a new filesystem object `path` and copies the contents of
///        `src` into it.
///
/// @param path The destination filesystem pathname
/// @param src  The data source
///
/// @remarks Errors are reported via C++ exceptions. When this function returns,
///          the seek pointer of `src` cannot be assumed to be valid.
///
void stream_to(fs::path path, IStream* src)
{
    // Validate input
    THROW_HR_IF_NULL(E_INVALIDARG, src);

    // Create an `IStream` over a filesystem object
    ::wil::com_ptr<IStream> file {};
    THROW_IF_FAILED(::SHCreateStreamOnFileEx(path.c_str(), STGM_WRITE | STGM_SHARE_DENY_WRITE | STGM_CREATE,
                                             FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, true, nullptr, file.put()));

    // Query source for its size in bytes
    auto size = ULARGE_INTEGER {};
    THROW_IF_FAILED(src->Seek({}, STREAM_SEEK_END, &size));
    // Reset source stream pointer to the beginning
    THROW_IF_FAILED(src->Seek({}, STREAM_SEEK_SET, nullptr));

    // Copy all bytes from the source stream into the file stream
    THROW_IF_FAILED(src->CopyTo(file.get(), size, nullptr, nullptr));
}
```

That's a lot of code, most of which is hard to comprehend. Thankfully, using it is not nearly as convoluted. Here is a C++ program that takes a screen capture and saves it to a file:

```cpp
int main()
{
    // Initialize COM
    THROW_IF_FAILED(::CoInitializeEx(nullptr, COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED | COINIT_DISABLE_OLE1DDE));

    auto const capture = capture_desktop();
    auto const stream = encode_bmp(capture.get());
    stream_to(L"output.bmp", stream.get());
}
```

Prerequisites for compiling the code above:

- Installation of the WIL; when using Visual Studio, the following *packages.config* will do

  ```xml
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <packages>
    <package id="Microsoft.Windows.ImplementationLibrary" version="1.0.231028.1" targetFramework="native" />
  </packages>
  ```
- A C++20 compiler due to use of [designated initializers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization#Designated_initializers)

---

<sup>1</sup> *The [BMP file format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format) is **incredibly** complex.*

<sup>2</sup> *This is based on the GDI and doesn't support certain render technologies (such as Direct3D). [Screen capture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/screen-capture) explains how to use the [`Windows.Graphics.Capture`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.graphics.capture) namespace. It is capable of capturing any window contents, but it is a fair bit more complex to manage.*

<sup>3</sup> *The code uses the [Windows Implementation Library (WIL)](https://github.com/microsoft/wil) for resource management and error reporting. Using the word "simple" may have set the wrong expectations.*

<sup>4</sup> *An alpha channel is really only meaningful in a multi-monitor setup where some parts of the desktop rectangle aren't covered by any monitor display surfaces.*